# How best to return a single value of different types from function

Tags: dynamic, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that returns either an error message (String) or a Firestore DocumentReference. I was planning to use a class containing both and testing if the error message is non-null to detect an error and if not then the reference is valid. I thought that was far too verbose however, and then thought it may be neater to return a var. Returning a var is not allowed however. Therefore I return a dynamic and test if result is String to detect an error.
IE.

```
   dynamic varResult = insertDoc(_sCollection,
     dataRec.toJson());
   if (varResult is String) {
```

Then after checking for compliance, I read the following from one of the gurus:
"It is bad style to explicitly mark a function as returning Dynamic (or var, or Any or whatever you choose to call it). It is very rare that you need to be aware of it (only when instantiating a generic with multiple type arguments where some are known and some are not)."

I'm quite happy using dynamic for the return value if that is appropriate, but generally I try to comply with best practice. I am also very aware of bloated software and I go to extremes to avoid it. That is why I didn't want to use a Class for the return value.

What is the best way to handle the above situation where the return type could be a String or alternatively some other object, in this case a Firestore DocumentReference (emphasis on very compact code)?

Comment: I think a typical approach would be to throw an `Exception` with the error message on failure and expect callers to catch it.

Comment: @ jamesdlin. Wouldn't that potentially result in a lot of duplicate code? If the exception is handled at the point where it occurs, then it can simply return an error message. To me that seems neater.

Comment: I don't see how it's worse than making callers check the type of the return value all the time.  Seems like about the same amount of code duplication to me.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create an abstract state class. Something like this:

```
abstract class DocumentInsertionState {
  const DocumentInsertionState();
}

class DocumentInsertionError extends DocumentInsertionState {
  final String message;

  const DocumentInsertionError(this.message);
}

class DocumentInsertionSuccess<T> extends DocumentInsertionState {
  final T object;

  const DocumentInsertionSuccess(this.object);
}

class Test {
  void doSomething() {
    final state = insertDoc();
    if (state is DocumentInsertionError) {

    }
  }

  DocumentInsertionState insertDoc() {
    try {
      return DocumentInsertionSuccess("It worked");
    } catch (e) {
      return DocumentInsertionError(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Full example here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/tree/master/example/flutter/github_search